# How to reconfigure Grub2 setup after moving from LVM to non-LVM setup

Tags: grub2, grub2-mkconfig

I reconfigured a Fedora installation from an LVM configuration to use plain partitions running EXT4.  Of course, `grub.cfg` still contains the old LVM mount names (`fedora_localhost-root`, `fedora_localhost-home`, etc.) so I am unable to boot.

I currently have three partitions: boot, root, and swap (but swap is out of scope here).  Is there a way for `grubby` or `grub-mkconfig` to figure this out and recreate the correct config files or will I need to do this manually?

If manually, which file is the correct location to make the edits?  I notice that on the boot partition the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file contains `default_kernelopts` which reference the old LVM paths but unsure if that is the correct place to edit.  The Grub2 docs imply that file is autogenerated.

Comment: Can you manually boot? Or use Supergrub? Or use Boot-Repair or chroot into install? You need to totally reinstall grub. And must know if UEFI or BIOS install to install correct version of grub. And have correct supporting partitions if gpt, either ESP (UEFI) or bios_grub (BIOS) is using gpt which you really should use.

Comment: Hey @oldfred I would boot manually if I knew how.  I will look for docs on how to do that.  Boot-repair is not working for me.  I ticked the box to reinstall Grub but the old paths persist.  This is on an older ThinkPad so BIOS for sure.  I will give Boot-Repair another go.  I am thinking I may need to install Fedora using standard partitions and then dd content from the old drive over to the new.  That would be a last resort though.

Comment: I am going to try Supergrub now.

Comment: Do not try to dd data, but use rsync to move data from old/backups to new partitions. DD's nickname is data destroyer & is really only for full drive to same size drive copy. Manual boot, you in effect type in your own boot stanza. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub.3E-1

Comment: Good call.  As an old HP-UX kernel developer I am used to using dd.  rsync is restartable and much simple.  The caveat being lots of mount points instead of raw devices.  Plus, it allows for exclusion of directories - in this case /home.  I'll have a go a copying the partitions to a new drive and only hacking the original if needed.   I see now that the default_kernelopts should just pass the UUID of the boot drive.  Much simpler without the LVM args.

Comment: Copying the partitions over to a new Fedora install worked really well until I booted.  Then, it is failing to find a hiberation file which must have been created during install so the OS fails to boot.  I think it I could tell it not to look for the hibernation file I would be good to go.

Comment: I have always preferred new install & restore from backups. It also confirms backups have everything you need when/if a drive totally fails & you have to do new install & restore. Besides Supergrub I have recently started using rEFInd as UEFI emergency boot. It is tiny (as is Supergrub) and I then found a use for an old 256MB flash drive as my rEFInd